# Dafny precondition to require a string is not only whitespace

Tags: dafny

I am trying to write a precondition to require a string to contain at least one non-whitespace character. I wrote the following:

```
predicate AllWhiteSpaceChars(s: string) {
    forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| ==> s[i] in {' ', '\n', /*'\f',*/ '\r', '\t'/*, '\v'*/}
}
```

But I can't get my program to verify with it. The following fails:

```
method test1(s: string)
    requires !AllWhiteSpaceChars(s)
{
    print s;
}

method test2()
{
    test1("./foo");
}
```

What is wrong with my predicate, and how can I create a working precondition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a trigger issue. The following works. But maybe someone more familiar with triggers can suggest a better fix.

```
predicate HasNonWhiteSpace(s: string) {
    if s == []
    then false
    else s[0] !in {' ', '\n', /*'\f',*/ '\r', '\t'/*, '\v'*/} || HasNonWhiteSpace(s[1..])
}

method test1(s: string)
    requires HasNonWhiteSpace(s)
{
    print s;
}

method test2()
{
    test1("./foo");
    test1("\t\n ");
    test1("d d");
}
```

BTW: not sure if you meant to require the string being printed to be non-empty. My current solution also requires that.